# How to condition TYPO3 Solr sortBy

Tags: solr, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

we have a TYPO3 project and use SOLR as search engine. i'm wondering how does a if-statement/conditional look like in the config files written in TypoScript?

TYPO3: 8.7
Apache Solr for TYPO3 - ES: 7.5.3

for example:  we use

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.query.sortBy = data_datax_title_stringS asc
```

as sort setting for the following facet block:

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets {
```

but we only want that sorting if a certain part of the url query string is empty (q= or q=Searchtext)

so the sortBy should be applied if the query string looks like

```
http://localhost/?tx_solr%5Bq%5D=&L=0&id=2883
```

and should not be applied on

```
http://localhost/?tx_solr%5Bq%5D=Searchtext&L=0&id=2883
```

here is the actual block:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id={$site.config.search_page_blasts}]

    plugin.tx_solr.search.targetPage = {$site.config.search_page_blasts}

config.defaultGetVars {
    tx_solr.filter.0 = result_type_filter:blast
}

plugin.tx_solr.search.query.sortBy = dynamic_field_A_stringS asc
plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets {

    facetX < lib.solr.facets.directBlast
    facetX.field = dynamic_field_X_boolS

}
```

any help is highly appreciated

edit: 
i found

```
plugin.tx_solr.search.query.getParameter = q
```

but this only defines the name for the query get-parameter in case another service needs a specific name. but i would need the value of this parameter and condition the sortBy by its value.

edit:

after some research im now at this state:  the sort works if a query string is set - but not if its empty

```
[globalVar = GP:q = ""]
    plugin.tx_solr.search.query.sortBy = wine_winery_title_stringS asc
[else]
    plugin.tx_solr.search.query.sortBy =
[end]

[globalVar = TSFE:id={$site.config.search_page_wineries}]
    plugin.tx_solr.search.targetPage = {$site.config.search_page_wineries}

    config.defaultGetVars {
        tx_solr.filter.0 = result_type_filter:winery
    }


    plugin.tx_solr.search.faceting.facets {

        direct_sale < lib.solr.facets.directSale
        direct_sale.field = winery_direct_sale_boolS
```

i dont really know how to format this the right way - nested conditions are not supported right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up extending the outer condition and just having two blocks for that page - i feels redundant but works perfectly fine. the condition outside of the existing one was not working - and nested conditions are not possible. so here is the solution:

with globalString to use regex for comparison

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id={$site.config.search_page_x}] && [globalString = GP:tx_solr|q = /.+/]
```

and globalVar for an empty parameter

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id={$site.config.search_page_x}] && [globalVar = GP:tx_solr|q =]
```

hope i can save someone a little time researching - thanks to everyone for their input

Answer (score 1):

We had a similiar use case and could not find a solution with existing featureset, so we ended up using a userfunction to check and redirect using the correct parameters.

Imo this is not the best way it should be solved though, so I am curious about other proposals.

```
# default sort by wine_winery_title_stringS
page.1558101700 = USER_INT
page.1558101700.userFunc = VENDOR\MyExt\UserFuncs\Solr->applyDefaultSorting
```

the userfunc could look like this:

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
public function applyDefaultSorting()
{
    $requestUrl = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getIndpEnv('TYPO3_REQUEST_URL');
    $solrParameters = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('tx_solr');

    $additionalParameterCharacter = '?';
    if(strpos($requestUrl, '?') !== false){
        $additionalParameterCharacter = '&';
    }
    // todo: get solr search parameter name from settings
    if(isset($solrParameters['q']) === false || empty($solrParameters['q'])){
        $redirectUri = $requestUrl . $additionalParameterCharacter . 'tx_solr[sort]=wine_winery_title_stringS+asc';

        header('Location: '.$redirectUri);
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
[globalVar = GP:q = ""]
    plugin.tx_solr.search.query.sortBy = wine_winery_title_stringS asc
[else]
    plugin.tx_solr.search.query.sortBy =
[end]
```

but with `[globalString = GP:q = /^$/]`?